# Wrapping a Queue in Future

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, multiprocessing, tornado

I am writing a Tornado webserver in Python 3.7 to display the status of processes run by the `multiprocessing` library.

The following code works, but I'd like to be able to do it using Tornado's built-in library instead of hacking in the threading library. I haven't figured out how to do it without blocking Tornado during `queue.get`. I think the correct solution is to wrap the `get` calls in some sort of future. I've tried for hours, but haven't figured out how to do this.

Inside of my multiprocessing script:

```
class ProcessToMonitor(multiprocessing.Process)

def __init__(self):
    multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
    self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

def run():
    while True:
        # do stuff
        self.queue.put(value)
```

Then, in my Tornado script

```
class MyWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    connections = set()

    def open(self):
        self.connections.add(self)

    def close(self):
        self.connections.remove(self)

    @classmethod
    def emit(self, message):
        [client.write_message(message) for client in self.connections]

def worker():
    ptm = ProcessToMonitor()
    ptm.start()
    while True:
        message = ptm.queue.get()
        MyWebSocket.emit(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', MainHandler), # Not shown
        (r'/websocket', MyWebSocket)
    ])
    app.listen(8888)

    threading.Thread(target=worker)

    ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    ioloop.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queue.get` isn't a blocking function, it just waits until there's an item in the queue in case the queue is empty. I can see from your code that `queue.get` fits perfectly for you use case inside a while loop.

I think you're probably using it incorrectly. You'll have to make the `worker` function a coroutine (`async`/`await` syntax):

```
async def worker():
    ...
    while True:
        message = await queue.get()
        ...
```

---

However, if you don't want to wait for an item and would like to proceed immediately, its alternative is [`queue.get_nowait`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html#tornado.queues.Queue.get_nowait).

One thing to note here is that`queue.get_nowait` will raise an exception called [`QueueEmpty`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html#tornado.queues.QueueEmpty) if the queue is empty. So, you'll need to handle that exception.

Example:

```
while True:
    try:
        message = queue.get_nowait()
    except QueueEmpty:
        # wait for some time before
        # next iteration
        # otherwise this loop will
        # keep running for no reason

    MyWebSocket.emit(message)
```

As you can see, you'll have to use pause the while loop for some time if the queue is empty to prevent it from overwhelming the system.

So why not use `queue.get` in the first place?

Comment: It sounds like this is just going to end up polling the queue. Is there a way to set up a listener/callback?

Comment: @JonathanWheeler The first example is not polling at all. Tornado will pause the coroutine at the `await` statement and will run it when `queue.get` returns an object. Pretty much what you'd do in a callback, but this has better syntax.